Associated bundles, vertical tangent bundles and classifying maps
Consider the following data:

a principal $G$-bundle $G\rightarrow P\rightarrow M$,

a manifold $F$ admitting a $G$-action $\rho: G\rightarrow \mathrm{Diff}(F)$.


We may construct a fiber bundle $P\times_{\rho} F$ over M with typical fiber $F$. Furthermore, there is an induced action
$$T\rho: G\rightarrow \mathrm{Diff}(TF)$$
defined as follows:
We view the tangent vectors in $TF$ as equivalence classes of smooth maps $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow N$. For a representative $\gamma$, we define that action of $g\in G$ on $\gamma$ by
$$T\rho_g(\gamma):=\rho_g\circ \gamma.$$
Then we may form the fiber bundle $P\times_{T\rho} TF$ over $M$. My questions are as follows:

By viewing $P\times_{T\rho} TF$ as a vector bundle over $P\times_\rho F$, can we claim that this bundle is the vertical tangent bundle of the fibration $P\times_\rho F\rightarrow M$?
Suppose the fibration $P\times_\rho F\rightarrow M$ is classified by
$$M\xrightarrow{f_P} BG\xrightarrow{B\rho} B\mathrm{Diff}(F)$$
and $P\times_{T\rho} TF \rightarrow M$ is classified by
$$M\xrightarrow{f_P} BG\xrightarrow{BT\rho} B\mathrm{Diff}(TF),$$
can we also write down the classifying map of $P\times_{T\rho} TF\rightarrow P\times_\rho F$ with the above data?

Any comment, correction, or reference recommendation would be greatly appreciated!
